# Some letters reordered

Tags: lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

My native English speaking friend gave me a piece of paper with the this on it.

> A H R B Q D W E F L M N S X G I J K O P C T V Y U Z

And he said: "Here is the alphabet. This is how it should be".
I was a bit puzzled, because I couldn't understand what he means, but I agreed with him after he explained his reasoning.

> What was his reasoning for putting the letters like this?

note: I didn't come up with this, but I cannot disclose the source for now because I would spoil it. I promise to do it after I get the answer.
Second note: This already got answered so here is the source:

> From one of my favorite people in the world: https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/259486092766625793

Comment: please explain the downvotes. don't hit and run

Comment: i explain my upvote:  Neil deGrasse Tyson!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> The letters are sorted by its name sound alphabetically

Comment: Damn it. I was hoping for at least 30 minutes until I get an answer. aaa...I mean Good job.

Comment: sorry, it was just searching on the internet. if the puzzle already exist ... ^^'

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> If you write each letter out in the way you pronounce its name, and alphabetize that list, you might get this.

As:

> A
>
>  H = aitch
>
>  R = ar
>
>  B = bee
>
>  Q = cue
>
>  D = dee
>
>  W = double u
>
>  E
>
>  F = ef
>
>  L = el
>
>  M = em
>
>  N = en
>
>  S = es
>
>  X = ex
>
>  G = gee
>
>  I
>
>  J = jay
>
>  K = kay
>
>  O
>
>  P = pee
>
>  C = see
>
>  T = tee
>
>  V = vee
>
>  Y = wye
>
>  U
>
>  Z = zee

Answer (score 4):

The order is ...

> ... alphabetically, but using the way the letters are pronounced when spelling:
>
>  A → a
>  H → aitch
>  R → ar
>  B → bee
>  Q → cue
>  D → dee
>  W → double u
>  E → e
>  F → eff
>  L → ell
>  M → em
>  N → en
>  S → es
>  X → ex
>  G → gee
>  I → i
>  J → jay
>  K → kay
>  O → o
>  P → pee
>  C → see
>  T → tee
>  V → vee
>  Y → why
>  U → u
>  Z → zed/zee
>
>  (I'm not sure whether there is a canonical representation of the letters. Also, the name for i should really be something like ay or eye; I've used the vowels themselves here, although all vowels except e are represented by diphtongs or at least compound sounds: /eɪ/,  /ʌɪ/, /əʊ/,  /juː/.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet#Letter_names

Comment: @f'': Very good, thanks. That list uses cee instead of see, which I find more intuitive, because it uses the letter it denotes.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about :

> Pronunciation! 
>
>  aye aich are bee cue dee double yoo ee eff ell ...

and your friend is :

> [Neil Degrasse Tyson](https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/259486092766625793)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> alphabet arranged phonetically